# I can't install any linux-based OS, as I'm getting the "Kernel panic - not syncing" error. Photo

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, 18.10

It seems that I can't install Ubuntu on my old Toshiba Satellite C650. Not only I can't install Ubuntu, I can't install any linux-based OS. I already tried Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 18.10 and the latest version of Linux Mint, and it's always the same error. I'm not trying to dual boot, I'm just trying to do a clean Ubuntu installation. Another thing worth mentioning is that whatever option I'm trying, it won't work.  [image: The error I receive no matter what linux-based OS I'm trying to install]

Comment: Use a search engine, and search for "toshiba satellite c650 +linux".

Comment: Dude, well, you saved my life.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having this problem, while botting you can press  which will get you into a menu. You gotta press  and then select . The Ubuntu installation will then boot.